# Why am i getting this discordAPIerror

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so i was trying to make a discord bot and it is giving me this error:

> DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
> 0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
> at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:287:15)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
> at async REST.request (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
> at async Client.client.handleCommands (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot\src\functions\handlers\handleCommands.js:28:9) {
> rawError: {
> code: 50035,
> errors: { '0': [Object] },
> message: 'Invalid Form Body'
> },
> code: 50035,
> status: 400,
> method: 'PUT',
> url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/1009341661572243516/guilds/688019305299706004/commands',
> requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
> }

the code is as follows:

```
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands');
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command, command.data.toJSON());
      }
    }

    const clientId = '1009341661572243516';
    const guildId = '688019305299706004';
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
    try {
      console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });
      console.log('Successfully reloaded application(/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```

command file:

```
 
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Returns a ping"),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const message = await interaction.deferReply({
      fetchReply: true,
    });
 
    const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\n Client Ping: ${
      message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp
    }`;
 
    await interaction.reply({
      content: newMessage,
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: How many command files do you have? There is an error with `data` property in one of your exported objects. Can you post them if it's not too many?

Comment: till now i just have one command file :

Answer (score 0):

The error is from your commandArray, you are pushing 2 elements but as you can see in the documentation (https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#guild-commands ), we just need to pass `command.data.toJSON()` and not `command, command.data.toJSON()`. I had the same issue and it worked for me.

Here is the right formated code

```js
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.handleCommands = async () => {
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands');
    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
      const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

      const { commands, commandArray } = client;
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
      }
    }

    const clientId = '1009341661572243516';
    const guildId = '688019305299706004';
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
    try {
      console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });
      console.log('Successfully reloaded application(/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
};
```